# Best method for Updating with Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Have a live "forum/blog", I am wanting to check the last id, and if changes fire jquery load.  I have this already accomplished.  But wanting to know the best method, or fastest to check latest id.

I have tried just selecting the latest id from the database.

```
$sql = "SELECT max(id) AS max FROM replies WHERE id = $id";
$result = $db->query($sql);
foreach($result as $last);
echo $last[max];
```

Or the other option upon submitting a reply. I am creating a txt file (or updating the text file) with the latest id. And then instead of using mysql I am using.

```
$file = file_get_contents("path/cache/$id.txt");
echo $file;
```

I am a novice by far.  One of these methods may not be the best either.  I am wanting to know the best method for server load, memory, and the best way to possibly handle 100 users at a time. I hope I explained it good enough.

The jquery code as requested.

```
<script>

var saved = '<?=$last[id]?>';

setInterval(function() { 
    $.ajax(
    {
        url: '/submit/check.php?tid=<?=$tid[1]?>',
        success: function(data) 
        {
           if (data != saved) 
            {
                $("#responsecontainer").load("/forum-content.php?tid=<?=$tid[1]?>", "", function() {
                jQuery(".timeago").timeago();
                });
                saved = data;
            }
        }
    });
}, 7000);

</script>
```

Comment: On the jQuery side, can you share what you've tried so far?

Comment: Added the jquery :)  Thanks!  Like I said, I am not very experienced.

Answer (score 0):

Data is undefined. My suggestion for your javascript code:

```
<script>

var saved = '<?=$last[id]?>';
var data = ""; //define "data"
setInterval(function() { 
    $.ajax(
    {
        url: '/submit/check.php?tid=<?=$tid[1]?>',
        success: function(data) 
        {
           if (data != saved) 
            {
                $("#responsecontainer").load("/forum-content.php?tid=<?=$tid[1]?>", "", function() {
                jQuery(".timeago").timeago();
                });
                //saved = data; //replace with:
                data = saved;
            }
        }
    });
}, 7000);

</script>
```

Your php code is also wrong:

```
$file = file_get_contents("path/cache/".$id.".txt"); //changed line
echo $file;
```

Hope this works for you!

Comment: well the script works.  I just rewrote it when I was typing. I was just trying to see what the best method was for memory, traffic, etc.

Comment: @user2639176 I would choose the database query solution... After all, 100 concurrent users is not to much load for a decent server...